# C/C++ to PHP (is there a LLVM backend in PHP)?

Tags: php, llvm, graphviz

I am looking for a project similar to Emscripten (LLVM backend for javascript) but for PHP.

It is for to "compile" graphviz to PHP such as https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js (in javascript).

Comment: Why do you need to compile it to PHP? You can run a binary compiled from the C code, or write a PHP extension.

Comment: Do you actually mean, you want a PHP library to compile a dataset to a graph composed as a static image?

Comment: Because the graphviz dependencies is too big, when you need only a headless server (LAMP for example), the graphviz package install half X system.

Comment: Emscripten has a WebAssembly backend, so it should be possible to run WebAssembly modules in PHP using [Wasmer PHP](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-php).